# 2D wire rope lattice static analysis. FEM/Lattice solution?

Tags: finite-element-method, lattices

I am looking for a relatively simple method to statically model a 2D lattice of wire ropes, with multiple fixed nodal connections between the wire ropes , fixed external nodes and multiple point force vectors acting at various positions on the ropes. The solution would be the node positions and inter-node tensions.

Is it possible to do this with FEM ?
I am wondering about the ability to:
1. Model extensible members with tensile stiffness E and zero flexional stiffness.
2. Deal with possible indeterminacy when any T<0.

Are there other ways to approach other than FEM ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am only at the pencil and paper stage.

Comment: But to be sure: you want to implement this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Yes, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two main choices:

- FEM: you'd need to look at beam elements and/or trusses; this is something that the Mathematica FEM does not have build in and most likely will never have because
- [SystemModeler](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/index.html) which uses lumped modeling and is a superb tool for this kind of job.